# Ruby memory issues with Kernel.open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wrestling with a memory issue on our production server. I am using a bioruby gem from within a delayed_job (in a Rails 4 app). Previously all worked fine, and it also works fine on the local development (OS X) machine.

There is plenty of memory on the server. It has 8Gb and is barely using 2GB. It does not change when the file is accessed.

The exact line of code that causes the error to occur is isseing a Kernel.open (line 35) : https://github.com/misshie/bioruby-ucsc-api/blob/master/lib/bio-ucsc/file/twobit.rb

```
def self.load(filename)
      two_bit = nil
      Kernel.open(filename, 'rb') {|f| two_bit = f.read}
      tbq = Bio::Ucsc::File::ByteQueue.new(two_bit)
```

The file it is trying to open contains the human genome, and is 800MB, but this process has been working fine for the past 9 months.

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > Kernel.open('/home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bin/hg19/hg19.2bit', 'rb') {|f| two_bit = f.read}
NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory
from (irb):1:in `read'
from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
from (irb):1:in `open'
from (irb):1
from /home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The server is Ubuntu 12

```
assay@assaypipeline:~/apps/assay/shared/bin/hg19$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

**EDIT**

In reponse to CMoi's comment below, I tried an open only, and it seemed be OK. Not sure how to proceed now.

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > Kernel.open('/home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bin/hg19/hg19.2bit', 'rb')
 => #<File:/home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bin/hg19/hg19.2bit>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I will add an EDIT

Comment: Why `Kernel.open` instead of `File.open`?

Comment: I don't know ... it's from a gem. I did try File.open and got the same error. No problems on my mac laptop with the same code & file.

Comment: Can you try with a newer version of Ruby?

Comment: What are you doing with this very heavy String object? Maybe take a look at enumerable chunk depending on what usage two_bit has.

Comment: @engineersmnky It is a file containing the full human DNA sequence. A string on any length can be extracted anywhere from within the file. Genome sequences are kept in files as they are too big for databases.

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried this

```
tbq = Bio::Ucsc::File::ByteQueue.new(File.open('/home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bin/hg19/hg19.2bit', &:read))
```

Or

```
tbq = Bio::Ucsc::File::ByteQueue.new(File.read('/home/assay/apps/assay/shared/bin/hg19/hg19.2bit'))
```

This will eliminate the block reading the file into a local variable and instead place it directly into your `Bio::Ucsc::File::ByteQueue` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both and received the same error. I think maybe there is some other issue, as this was working up until recently. I will try with a new blank server and see if it happens.